# Xamarin Live Player does not load shared libraries all the time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-live-player

**Context:** 
I have a Xamarin Android project that calls a shared library (.so) and I'm using Live Player to run the app on my device.

**Problem:**
The app only runs fine sometimes. When it doesn't, I get no exception at Visual Studio and I only get a one-line exception from the Live Player on my phone as follows:

> [LogEntry: Time=7/10/2018 4:42:26 PM -07:00, Level=Error,
>   Title=Visualization Error, Message=No body on method System.Int32
>   TestMobileLib.LibFacade::getInt(System.UInt32) (NInterpretException)]

**Attempts:**

- I tried uninstalling the apk from my phone. It doesn't work all the time.
- I also tried renaming the Android application package name to make it look like a new app. Doesn't work all the time either
- Reinstalled the Live Player. No luck.
- Re-paired my phone. No luck.
- Tried it on a different device. Same random behavior.
- Restarted the machine. No luck

Any assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1) I would report it as an issue via http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com and 2) Live is not a full runtime/debug environment... it does not replace directly deploying against simulators/emulators/devices.

Comment: Thanks Sushil, but I'm deploying the app on my device via Live Player. Isn't this a "good enough" runtime environment?

Comment: The best way is to use a emulator, or connect a Real Device. Live Player is still not that stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above by SuhiHangover and Bruno, I figured out the difference between running an app via Live Player vs. on the device itself. While Both solutions run the app on your device, the latter is much more stable at least when the project depends on a set of user-defined shared libraries.

As also noted in [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/338977#Comment_338977), Live Player seems to be optimal to support rapid prototyping on device, where changes you make the front-end markup (e.g., XAML files) can be instantly synchronized wirelessly. Xamarin Live Player, however, is limited when more need to be tested. The list of limitations are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android).